# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Element") to str

Tags: python

Ok so Im having a problem when printing something

Error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Element") to str
```

Code:

```
print(('Currently the weather in '+ query + 'is' + weath + 'with the temperature at ' + temp + 'degrees celsius'))
```

Comment: `Element` is a custom class, implement the `__str__` method

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. What are `query`, `weath` and `temp`, and which one is causing the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are two issues here. One is that, exactly as the error message tells you, strings can only be combined with other strings using `+`. One of those variables isn't a `str`, so a different approach is needed. The other problem is that the `Element` class might not look like anything you expect when printed. Please see the linked duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For a custom string representation of an instance

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


print('string ' + str(A('concatenation')))
#string concatenation
```

Without `__str__`

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

print('string ' + str(B('concatenation')))
#string <__main__.B object at 0x7f91f5dd5040>
```